# Windows SDK License

Tags: winapi, licensing

A simple question I suppose, with a potentially complicated answer:

> Is the Windows SDK free as in Beer?

I know it provides virtually the same compilers and commandline tools that the paid versions provide, and I believe you can only (legally) use it on a Windows machine, but am not even sure of anything more...

I'm not well versed in lawyer-talk, I hope someone here is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: @KevinBrown The meta post you linked is about questions about licencing your own software. This question is about the licencing terms of a software development tool, making it a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, yes, it is free. SDK license agreement is placed at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\License\License.htm (actual directory and version may be different in your case). Most important points:

Installation and Use.  One user may install and use any number of copies of the software on your devices to design, develop and test your programs that run on a Microsoft Windows operating system.

Distributable Code.  The software contains code that you are permitted to distribute in programs you develop if you comply with the terms below ...

The software is licensed, not sold. This agreement only gives you some rights to use the software.  Microsoft reserves all other rights.

Because this software is “as is,” we may not provide support services for it.